# I want to install windows 7 into my laptop that currently runs Kali Linux

Tags: windows-7, multi-boot

I need help on installing windows 7 alongside Kali Linux. My older laptop has both windows 7 and Kali Linux but I can't remember how I set up the dual boot from Windows 7 to install Kali Linux.

So I need help in the best way possible to install Windows 7 (I already have the Win7 installation ISO DVD) into my laptop and activate the dual boot option.

You can advise on assisting me from making a proper  partition to be used for the windows 7 from Kali Live gparted. (I don't have much data on my Kali Linux which I store into an external HDD for back up purposes.)

Quick response will be highly appreciated. If you need any clarification of what my question entails, kindly please ask for clarification.

Otherwise, I'll appreciate the help. Thanks

Answer (score -1):

Hi you create a new partition with gparted in kali.
After that you install windows with USB key.
Finally you boot kali from an USB key in try without installing mode and you reinstall the grub on your disk with chroot.

Comment: While these may be helpful general steps, you should provide specific information for each step, laying out what needs to be done. Right now this is more of a comment than an actual answer.

Comment: @BtPython, thanks for your response. However, I uninstalled Kali and Windows 7 was re-installed. Kindly assist me with full steps on how to install Kali and as well not remove windows 7. My older laptop has this but I honestly cannot remember how I made it into dual boot. So, I would appreciate the full steps and ensure that the installation of Kali doesn't mess with my windows partion

Comment: Currently, my local disk c: is 74.2gb/102Gb. Disk D: 97.0/129gb. So, I generally know the needed storage space for Kali is 10-20gb at least. So, into which partion should I create the partion without messing with my windows 7 partion?

Comment: 1)You create an partition with windows in disk management on the disk where there is the c partition

Comment: 2) boot from your USB key. When the partition menu appears select the partition that you created in windows.

Comment: 3) when you reboot your computer after the installation is finished you will not view your windows in grub but don’t panic juste boot kali and in terminal enter:update-grub and reboot